# Garbage data while reading a file using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

I am trying to write some meta information about a file by using 1024 bytes at the end of the file.

```
var buffer = new Buffer(1024);
buffer.write(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Once the string is copies to the buffer I am saving the file like this -

```
fs.write(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, fileSize,callback);
```

When I read the file I just want to extract the meta information saved in the **data** variable. I am doing this like this -

```
buffer = new Buffer(1024);
fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, fileSize, function(err, count, buffer) {
console.log(buffer.toJSON())
}
```

Unfortunately the above procedure gets the json data but has some garbage data surrounding it. buffer.toJSON() method thus fails. What should be my approach for such a problem?

**Edit:**
The buffer does not get completely filled.

**Current Solution:**
1. Fill the Buffer with null.
2. Use JSON5 to parse the json content.

**Final Solution**
1. Fill the Buffer with ' '
2. Use JSON parse to parse Json Content

Comment: Sounds like your buffer isn't getting full.  Buffers, when instantiated, can contain other data.

Comment: Yes my buffer remains empty.

Comment: What Brad was trying to say, is that when you create a buffer, it does not initialize the memory values to 0, so your erroneous data is likely coming from the fact that you're creating a buffer that is too large to contain your data.  The values that you believe are remaining "empty" are actually random bits(perhaps not random, but leftover from other values you've stored at these memory adresses, that have been freed).  Either initialize your buffer to empty strings, or create a buffer that is exactly the length that you need to store your data.

Comment: @ChrisCM Filling the buffer with null also creates an issue in json parse.

Comment: I said to initialize your buffer with empty strings, not null, null and empty are very different.  In your case, to cooperate with your JSON parser, "empty" in this case is likely setting each character to a space character.  You could also choose my alternative comment, which was to create a buffer that was exactly the size that you need.

Comment: Initializing the buffer with ' ' worked like a charm. Thanks!